# Execute Azure Billing Usage API using PublishSettings file via C# Code

Tags: api, billing

Trying to use Azure Billing Usage API using PublishSettings file using C# but not able to pass token in header.
I can make it work via passing my userid/password but it will not help if I want to automate the billing process. 
Any pointers will definitely help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Providing some code snippet will help others in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Billing API without being prompted for credentials using a [service principal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/), there are too many steps to fit it here but you can look at this [post](http://www.francoisdelport.com/2016/02/calling-azure-billing-api-unattended/) for details.